# Setting the right size of the NettyWorker pool

Tags: java, netty

I'm using Netty 3.7.0 and having an ExecutionHandler (OMATPE) added as first element in my ChannelPipeline.

**Q1**: Having this setup it should be safe to set the size of the WorkerPool to 1 since it just creates ChannelDownstreamEventRunnable which is added to the Executor provided by the ExecutionHandler. Or am I missing something here?

**Q2**: I also have some decoders in the pipeline so the decoding-work is done by an ExecutionHandler-Thread. Is this some kind of a "bad practice"? I.e. when the ExecutionHandler-Threads block? But then the queue of the ExecutionHandler's Executor should just increase and connections could still be handled by WorkerPool.

Answer (score 0):

A1. Yes, threads from worker pool just accept incoming connections and 1 thread in the pool seems to be enough.
A2. It depends on your application. If you just read from the channel, blocking of the Executor thread is safe and will serve as flow control. But in some cases blocking of read procesing will block messages sending and can lead to a deadlock. So in common, since Netty has asynchronous nature, you shouldn't block executor threads, IMHO)

Comment: _But in some cases blocking of read procesing will block messages sending and can lead to a deadlock._ In my case messages are sent by the ExecutionHandler-Thread as well, so there shouldn't be a race or something.

Comment: If you set the maxTotalMemorySize Netty the executor blocks the I/O threads when the value is breached, rather than preventing all channels from reading. If your executor thread blocks waiting for writes to finish you could end up in a deadlock. Either don't set the maxTotalMemorySize parameter or don't block the executor thread

Comment: I have set the maxTotalMemorySize to 0, so the executor threads shouldn't wait or block.